# Custom view based on time slots

Tags: fullcalendar

Instead of a 7 day week, I want to split saturday and sunday into 3 different days / time slots.  So you have monday through friday, then sat morning, sat afternoon and sat evening.  Same for sunday, giving me a grid of 11 days.
Any ideas on how I'd configure fullcalendar to do this?

Comment: I think you'd need a completely custom view for this. As far as I know it's not possible for each section of the view to be a different length using the standard functionality. Also how would it look? If you have Sat morning side-by-side in your grid with Sat afternoon, how would you draw the differing timeslots so it was clear? It sounds like it could be confusing to the user at the very least. A standard agendaWeek view shows them all the same info already.

Comment: If you really want to do it, see the second half of this page, but it's quite a length and time-consuming task to create a whole new view: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: Is this still the case?  I can see some time slot stuff in the scheduler now.  Looked at the custom view stuff, but would benefit from some examples on how this works

Comment: the only examples of views are the ones already implemented in fullCalendar, which you're free to look at the source code for. Also what "time slot stuff" are you referring to precisely? There have been no recent changes which would allow you to fulfil your requirement, unless you can point me to it? AFAIK you still can't have an uneven spread of timeslots on the grid.